# How to safely add values to grpc ServerStream in interceptor

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I have a logging interceptor for my grpc server and want to add a value to the metadata (I want to track the request throughout its lifetime):

```
func (m *middleware) loggingInterceptor(srv interface{},
    ss grpc.ServerStream,
    info *grpc.StreamServerInfo,
    handler grpc.StreamHandler) 

    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ss.Context())
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("could not get metadata from incoming stream context")
    }

    // add the transaction id to the metadata so that business logic can track it
    md.Append("trans-id", "some-transaction-id")

    // call the handler func
    return handler(srv, ss)
}
```

but the docs for `FromIncomingContext` state that:

```
// FromIncomingContext returns the incoming metadata in ctx if it exists.  The
// returned MD should not be modified. Writing to it may cause races.
// Modification should be made to copies of the returned MD.
```

Ok, so I look at the copy function and copy the metadata:

```
mdCopy := md.Copy()
mdCopy.Append("trans-id", "some-transaction-id")
```

and think "how do I attach this metadata back to the `ServerStream` context?", and I check if there's some `ss.SetContext(newCtx)`, but I don't see anything of the sort. Am I thinking about this from the wrong perspective, or am I missing something else?

Comment: You could find the sample of `wrappedStream` from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74148611/3011380

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use [NewIncomingContext](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/metadata#NewIncomingContext) to create a copy of the current context in the stream.

Then you would have to create a `wrappedStream` type which overrides `Context` method in `ServerStream` to return the modified `context`. You would need to pass this `wrappedStream` to the `handler` that you received in your interceptor.

You can see an example of this here (it overrides other methods here, but the idea is the same): 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/features/interceptor/server/main.go#L106-L124

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Easwar is right.

You can either create your own ServerStream implementation, override Context() method with your own context or there's struct inside grpc package which is `WrappedServerStream` `(github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware)` which you can pass context and original server stream object and use it inside `handler`.

Example:

```
    // This methods get the current context, and creates a new one
    newContext, err := interceptor.authorize(ss.Context(), info.FullMethod)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("authorization failed: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    
    err = handler(srv, &grpc_middleware.WrappedServerStream{
        ServerStream:   ss,
        WrappedContext: newContext,
    })
```