# Modifying metadata on Go GRPC server streaming interceptor

Tags: go, grpc-go

I've been trying to set metadata on a server stream interceptor so they could be read downstream by the actual RPC function:

```
func UserIDInterceptor(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
    ss.SendHeader(metadata.New(map[string]string{"X-User-Id": "real_user_id"}))
    return handler(srv, ss)
}

func (server *Server) GetObjects(req *iam.GetObjectsRequest, client iam.Service_GetObjectsServer) error {
    ctx := client.Context()
    userID, ok := HeaderFromMetadata(ctx, "X-User-Id")

    log.Printf("User ID: %s, Ok: %t\n", userID, ok)
    return nil
}

func HeaderFromMetadata(ctx context.Context, headers ...string) (string, bool) {
    meta, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
    if !ok {
        return "", false
    }

    for _, header := range headers {
        if value := meta.Get(header); len(value) > 0 {
            return value[0], true
        }
    }

    return "", false
}
```

And my server is registered like this:

```
server := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc.StreamInterceptor(UserIDInterceptor))
RegisterIAMServer(server, NewServer())
```

The problem I'm having is that the user ID header isn't being found. I can see that the interceptor is called when the client sends the request, and I can see that the metadata contains the header, but the actual RPC can't seem to extract it. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

The more simple solution is only override the `Context()` method of `ServerStream`

```golang
type serverStream struct {
    grpc.ServerStream
    ctx context.Context
}

func (s *serverStream) Context() context.Context {
    return s.ctx
}

func UserIDInterceptor(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ss.Context())
    if ok {
        md.Append("X-User-Id", "real_user_id")
    }
    newCtx := metadata.NewIncomingContext(ss.Context(), md)

    return handler(srv, &serverStream{ss, newCtx})
}
```

---

**Update**

Another simple solution is to define one wrapper to `grpc.ServerStream` as below

```golang
type serverStreamWrapper struct {
    ss  grpc.ServerStream
    ctx context.Context
}

func (w serverStreamWrapper) Context() context.Context        { return w.ctx }
func (w serverStreamWrapper) RecvMsg(msg interface{}) error   { return w.ss.RecvMsg(msg) }
func (w serverStreamWrapper) SendMsg(msg interface{}) error   { return w.ss.SendMsg(msg) }
func (w serverStreamWrapper) SendHeader(md metadata.MD) error { return w.ss.SendHeader(md) }
func (w serverStreamWrapper) SetHeader(md metadata.MD) error  { return w.ss.SetHeader(md) }
func (w serverStreamWrapper) SetTrailer(md metadata.MD)       { w.ss.SetTrailer(md) }

func UserIDInterceptor(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ss.Context())
    if ok {
        md.Append("X-User-Id", "real_user_id")
    }
    newCtx := metadata.NewIncomingContext(ss.Context(), md)

    return handler(srv, serverStreamWrapper{ss, newCtx})
}
```

---

You could use [NewIncomingContext](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/metadata#NewIncomingContext) to create a copy of the current context in the stream.

Since there is no method to set the `context` of `grpc.ServerStream`, in order to set the context back to `ServerStream`, the `wrappedStream` is defined with `context.Context`, and `SetContext` method to set `context.Context`

```golang
type wrappedStream struct {
    grpc.ServerStream
    ctx context.Context
}

func (w *wrappedStream) SetContext(ctx context.Context) {
    w.ctx = ctx
}
```

Full sample codes

```golang
type wrappedStream struct {
    grpc.ServerStream
    ctx context.Context
}

func (w *wrappedStream) Context() context.Context {
    return w.ctx
}

func (w *wrappedStream) SetContext(ctx context.Context) {
    w.ctx = ctx
}

func (w *wrappedStream) RecvMsg(m interface{}) error {
    return w.ServerStream.RecvMsg(m)
}

func (w *wrappedStream) SendMsg(m interface{}) error {
    return w.ServerStream.SendMsg(m)
}

type StreamContextWrapper interface {
    grpc.ServerStream
    SetContext(context.Context)
}

func newStreamContextWrapper(ss grpc.ServerStream) StreamContextWrapper {
    ctx := ss.Context()
    return &wrappedStream{
        ss,
        ctx,
    }
}

func UserIDInterceptor(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ss.Context())
    if ok {
        md.Append("X-User-Id", "real_user_id")
    }
    newCtx := metadata.NewIncomingContext(ss.Context(), md)

    sw := newStreamContextWrapper(ss)
    sw.SetContext(newCtx)

    return handler(srv, sw)
}
```